# Is it possible to run a method only if it has not yet been run on the current day?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a project that makes API calls to get data on release dates for movies. Currently, every time I load up an activity, I loop through the release dates saved on the device, and make several API calls to compare the data on the device to the data that the API returns. However, because I am dealing with "release dates," running this check a single time per day would be more than enough. Now here is the catch: This activity can be opened and closed several times by the user per day! So my question is: **Is there some way to check and ensure that a method is only executed if it has NOT yet been executed on the current day?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without some sort of backing store, i.e. a file or database table to tell you, for example, the last run time.

Comment: Oh I see, so maybe just create a database that stores the date, and then compare the current date to the one stored in the database. Thanks, I can do this.

Comment: Maybe also give user the option to 'force' the code to run even if it's been run once?